# How to wrap an auto dimension image element tightly in a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say for example I have an image that preserves aspect ratio, ie, auto scaled with

```
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

I now need to contain this inside a container which wraps it perfectly tight with something like

```
.wrapper{
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     background:pink; /*verify*/
 }
```

But the wrapper leaves extra space at the corners. How could you solve this ? The HTML is as simple as

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Here's a snippet of the code:

```css
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.wrapper{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:pink; /*verify*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the paddings? Are you using any css frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). Therefore it spans the width that is available. If you want the wrapper element to wrap around the image without extra space you could set it's display property to `inline-flex`. This sets the wrapper width to the width and height of it's content.

I've set an extra padding of 2 pixels in the example to visualise the wrapping.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x400" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try the following:

```
<img src="img.jpg" border=1 style="padding:50px;border:1px solid red">
```

By changing the "padding" setting to control the space between the border and the image.

Answer (score 0):

don't give height and width to the wrapper, by doing so it will take its parent as reference. In your case wrapper will be 100% of parent height and 100% of parent width.

you can make the wrapper like this

```css
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
.wrapper{
     background:pink; /*verify*/
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
</div>
```

By using `display:inline-block` for the wrapper, you are saying the browser to treat this element as inline not as block. So it will expand itself to accommodate its children if its `height` and `width` are not specified and it will not consume the whole width as the block elements do.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 100% `height` and `width` from the wrapper as these values reference the wrapper's parent not it's contents. You can then set the wrapper's `display` to `inline-block` to make it stick to the dimensions of it's contents.

A final fix involves setting the `vertical-align: middle;` property to remove the space below the image that is caused by the browser allowing space for characters that hang below the baseline (g, y etc.)

Check out the snippet below:

```css
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    background:pink; /*verify*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200"/>
</div>
```